# R: clear output file before writing

Tags: r

I want to clear the file of previous inputs before doing the loop.
Here's the script

```
write("", outfile, append=FALSE)

for (i in 1:3)
  write(i,outfile, append=TRUE)
```

What it does is

```
//empty line
1
2
3
```

The`write` command puts a newline after the "" and if I use `cat` it doesn't write anything and append does not register, it appends new run to the previous. Run twice:

```
cat("", outfile, append=FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(outlist))
  write(i,outfile, append=TRUE)
```

The result is:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

So I want to either to remove the empty line `write` makes or some function or command to clear file before writing.

Comment: Put an if statement that changes behavior for first iteration of loop.

Comment: such as `write(i, outfile, append = i != 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `outfile` is the path to the file, then

```
close( file( outfile, open="w" ) )
```

opens the file for writing, and closes it immediately. Then the file exists, but is empty.

Example:

```
close( file( outfile, open="w" ) )
print(readLines(outfile))
# character(0)

for (i in 1:3)
  write(i,outfile, append=TRUE)

print(readLines(outfile))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"

#-----------------------------------------

close( file( outfile, open="w" ) )

for (i in 1:3)
  write(i,outfile, append=TRUE)

print(readLines(outfile))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"

#-----------------------------------------

close( file( outfile, open="w" ) )

for (i in 4:5)
  write(i,outfile, append=TRUE)

print(readLines(outfile))
# [1] "4" "5"
```